# .htaccess in Codeigniter is not working in remote server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

.htaccess File is working fine in my localhost
But when I upload it on the remote server the redirection is not working properly.

When I logged in with any user and then try to logout from the site then it is again showing me logged in but it works fine on my local web server

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

<Files "index.php">
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

This my logout controller

```
  <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


 class logout extends CI_Controller { 

public function __construct()
{
     parent::__construct();
}

function index()
{
    $this->home_model->unsetsessions();
    redirect('', 'refresh');
}
}?>
```

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem with your .htaccess. Please let us have a closer look to your controller actions.

Comment: Yes it's not your .htaccess issue rather there will be issue with your controller code or may be improper base_url.

if you can post your logout code more help can be provided.

Comment: I have Inseted Logout Controller

Comment: Don't know what you are using in unsetsessions() in your model.but i hope you are using the correct one for destroying the sessions.

Regarding your redirection,don't do it that way specify the controller name where you want to redirect and if you want to redirect to your home,you can try this out
`redirect(base_url(),'refresh')`

Comment: Wait. Can you confirm that your web server is using Apache, instead of IIS? IIS does not support `.htaccess`

Comment: I am using Apache web server

Comment: Actually my problem is that when I click on the logout it does not log's out properly then when I press F5 and refresh then it gets log out

Answer (score 0):

This .htaccess is working good in my CI projects:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    # activate RewriteEngine
    RewriteEngine on

    # delete index.php from URL
    RewriteCond $1 !(index\.php|robots\.txt|humans\.txt|license\.txt|sitemap\.xml|assets)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]

    # sitemap.xml to /sitemap
    RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ index.php/sitemap [L]

    # no-www to www
    #change DOMNIO.COM
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DOMNIO.COM$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.DOMNIO.COM/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Actually my problem is that when I click on the logout it does not log's out properly then when I press F5 and refresh then it gets log out